# How to add an input variable in terraform terraform.tfvars from JSON file?

Tags: azure, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, terraform-template-file

How to add an input variable in terraform terraform.tfvars from JSON file ?

I have written a Terraform code for a snowflake. Now I have defined the input variables manually in terraform.tfvars but I would like to integrate the input in JSON format as an input variable for terraform.tfvars

Does anyone have any example like get an input variable in JSON format and include in terraform.tfvars and run terraform code.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of what you've tried so far and any errors you got when you ran it please?

Comment: eg:- 

current data of my terraform.tfvars file 

warehouse_name              = "NAME"
warehouse_size              = "xxxxx"
max_cluster_count           = 2
database_name               = "DB8"

now I am manually adding these variables. I am planning to get the input in JSON format and divert it on terraform,tfvars. 

I was looking for help regarding how to convert JSON format data in HCL language.

Comment: You should edit your question to include your [mcve]. It's probably worth reading that link to see what a good example looks like to help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be [`json2hcl`](https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl). All what you need is intall the tool

```
curl -SsL https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl/releases/download/v0.0.6/json2hcl_v0.0.6_darwin_amd64 \
  | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/json2hcl > /dev/null && sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/json2hcl && json2hcl -version
```

and then run it as follows:

```
$ json2hcl < fixtures/infra.tf.json
"output" "arn" {
  "value" = "${aws_dynamodb_table.basic-dynamodb-table.arn}"
}
... rest of HCL truncated
```

Comment: Getting following error.. 

 cannot execute binary file: Exec format error